# Classifying singularities and finding their residues

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

How would one find the residues of:

$f(z)=z/cos(z)$

I believe that the singularities are $z=\pi/2 + 2k\pi$ where k is an integer, but I'm not sure how to go about classifying them and then finding their residues.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(z) = \cos z$. Since $g'(z) = -\sin z$, we see that $h'(z) \neq 0$ wherever $h(z) = 0$. In other words, all the zeros of $\cos z$ are simple.

Hence all the poles of $f$ are simple as well (the zero of $z$ occurs at a point where $\cos z \neq 0$). To compute the residues, use
$$
\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=a} \frac{g(z)}{h(z)} = \frac{g(a)}{h'(a)}
$$
which is valid at points where $h$ has simple zeros.